# Phantomjs - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS script that works when I run it locally (Mac), but when I run it on my Linux server, it returns the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/value_form:5712 in global code
```

The code is:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var args = require('system').args;
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';

page.open('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/value_form', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
        var result ="";
        // ...
        return result;
    });    

    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: why not just do request to this url: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static  ? I don't see the benefit of using phantomjs, cuz in real it automatically requests api and gets the data.

Comment: Wow... I cant believe that actually exists, thanks!

Comment: Which **PhantomJS versions** do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Using 2.1.1. When I register to those error messages, I get the following: Unable to load resource (#2 URL:https://ismdj.scdn5.secure.raxcdn.com/static/CACHE/css/f021cc36944b.css)
...
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
TRACE:
 -> https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/value_form: 5712 (in function "global code")
Perhaps its an SSL issue?

Comment: I am getting the same errors as described in the original problem as well as with the registered events per @ArtjomB above. Any further thoughts on resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a race condition between your code and jQuery being loaded on the page. Wrap the statements in your `page.evaluate` callback with a `$(document).ready(function() { /* your statements here */ });` to ensure scripts on the page have loaded fully.

Comment: The DOM is ready when the `page.open` callback is called. Also, `$` is *only* accessible inside of [`page.evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). You can't use `$` outside of `page.evaluate`

Comment: you can't use $(document). if jQuery has not loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still using PhantomJS and encounters this problem, I solved it with

`phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes`

Answer (score -5):

I don't intend for upvote.
I'm providing solution to solve some situations without simulating browser behavior with phantomjs just to retrieve data that can be handled directly by requesting to url.

You need the data from the page, so why not just do request to this url: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static

```
var request = require('request'); // install: npm i request
var fs = require('fs');
var args = require('system').args;

request.get({url: 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static'}, function(err, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

How I found this url?

Simple:

[image: firebug inspect net]

Comment: The request package is written for node.js and will not work with PhantomJS. You might have helped the OP, but you haven't yet answered the question.

Comment: Dear @ArtjomB ! I'm answering with solution that Phill needs. And he needs just to grab data from another site. That's why I'm saying that no need for phantomjs when there is direct url that returns all data as json. SO is the place where we help to solve their problems. And my solution solved the problem of parsing data. I see You're wise, so answer with solution, not just downvoting other's answers and commenting. It's not the way that noble people do.

Comment: That's still not going to help people that want to use PhantomJS and come here for *"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $"*. The question doesn't contain a single word to support your argument that OP just wanted to download some JSON from the page and nothing else. Voting is a form of quality control. Your answer is fine on its own, but it has nothing to do with the question as it was asked and I want to keep frustration for future readers at a minimum. I feel very noble doing this.

Comment: @ArtjomB. happy for You (: